# Function succeeds with constant as parameter but fails with variable as parameter

Tags: c++, ncurses

"Fails" in the sense that the function does not work as expected.

I am trying to add color to wide chars with NCurses.  The following function correctly displays the text --- but only in the terminal's default color, regardless the value of `pair`, a color pair.  (`pair` holds the correct value after the `wattr_get` macro, per GDB.)  If I substitute `pair` with a constant (like `4`), the function writes the text correctly and in color.

I've spend some quality time with GDB and the NCurses 5.9 source code, but am at a loss to explain why a constant works but a variable won't.

```
void color_write( const std::wstring &w ) {
    // Convert to cchar_t for NCurses
    attr_t attrs;
    short pair;
    wattr_get( window_, &attrs, &pair, nullptr );  
    std::vector< cchar_t > color_str;
    std::wstring wt;
    cchar_t ct;
    for( auto& i: w ) {
        wt = i;
        if( OK != ::setcchar( &ct, wt.c_str(), attrs, pair, nullptr ) ) throw;
        color_str.push_back( ct );
    }
    ct.chars[0] = 0;
    color_str.push_back( ct );
    ::wadd_wchnstr( window_, color_str.data(), -1 );
}
```

Comment: Look for overloaded methods with differing types for the "pair" argument.  par is a short, 4 is a const int. (try casting pair to be a const int in the call to see if that helps.)

Comment: @DaleWilson the cast does not help --- same problem.  setcchar() asks for a `short`, so I've tried both ways (`const short` and `const int`).  I'm thoroughly confused, as GDB's backtrace claims the parameters are the same either way.

Comment: The only other potential problem I see is the throw. A throw without something to throw should only be used in a catch block.  Try throw "oops";  [grasping at straws]